# document.body.querySelectorAll() fails but document.getElementsByClassName() works

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors, selectors-api

I had to get some elements in a form to change their style `onchange` of a `<select>`. I added the class `new_cat_inputs` to the elements and I thought I'd get them by `document.querySelectorAll()`.
I tried many things but it never worked, I finally used :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("new_cat_inputs")
```

It means my problem have been solved but I want to understand.
Here is what I tried before:

```
// first attempt, as I'd have used document.querySelector() which works this way
document.querySelectorAll(".new_cat_inputs");

// Logs an error which says it can't read the property "querySelectorAll" of null (body)
document.body.querySelectorAll(".new_cat_inputs");

// doesn't get the elements neither as the 1st attempt. Neither with document.body
document.querySelectorAll("label.new_cat_inputs, input.new_cat_inputs, select.new_cat_inputs");
```

I read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which often helps but not this time.
What is the correct way to **select multiple DOM elements** by their **class** in the *whole document* by the function `document.querySelectorAll()` ?

Comment: In your example, document.body is `null`, so maybe your DOM wasn't loaded, did you try to put your code inside this event listener : `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // your code 
})`
?

Comment: @boehm_s you are right, the `window.onload` wasn't enough

Comment: but still... why does `document.getElementsByClassName()` works and not `document.querySelectorAll()` ? @boehm_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `document.body` seems to be `null` in your example, that means that the DOM is not loaded.
the following event listener allows you to wait for the DOM to be loaded and then execute your code :

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // your code
})
```

I think (i'm not sure) that yout `getElementsByClassName` worked because you used it in another place or when the DOM was loaded. And since this method returns a **live** `HTMLCollection`, it was updated when the DOM has been loaded.

See [the following link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

Cheers,

Comment: I used both functions in the same place, but your explanation about the live `HTMLCollection` makes more sense. Thanks a lot, I learnt today !